# Using CDK Secret in other Stacks fails when Secret has own KMS key

Tags: c#, aws-cdk, amazon-kms

I'm trying to split up a CDK app in multiple stacks, with one stack containing some secrets that will be referenced by the other stacks

If I create secrets with my own KMS key, the cdk app will error out and give cyclic reference detected

```
Error: 'SecretStack' depends on 'RoleStack' (SecretStack -> RoleStack/TheRole/Resource.Arn). Adding this dependency (RoleStack -> SecretStack/TheSecret/Resource.Ref) would create a cyclic reference
```

If I remove the usage of of my own key, the `cdk diff` command works fine

Is it achievable to use my own key with multiple stacks like this and how would I do to avoid the cyclic reference?

Here is a reproduceable example

```
public class SecretStack : Stack
{
    public SecretStack(Construct scope, string id, IStackProps props = null) : base(scope, id, props)
    {
        var mainKey = new Key(this, "MainKey");

        TheSecret = new Secret(this, "TheSecret", new SecretProps
        {
            EncryptionKey = mainKey
        });
    }

    public Secret TheSecret { get; }
}


public class RoleStack : Stack
{
    public RoleStack(Construct scope, SecretStack secretStack, string id, IStackProps props = null) : base(scope, id, props)
    {
        var theRole = new Role(this, "TheRole", new RoleProps
        {
            AssumedBy = new ServicePrincipal("lambda.amazonaws.com")
        });

        secretStack.TheSecret.GrantRead(theRole);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/14213) issue with how CDK grants KMS permissions to resources in another stack. Until that is fixed, the workaround is to avoid using `grantRead` method and instead add IAM policy directly to the role using `addToPolicy` method on `theRole`. You would need to add two policies to your role:

```
{
            effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
            actions: ['secretsmanager:GetSecretValue', 'secretsmanager:DescribeSecret'],
            resources: [secretStack.TheSecret.SecretArn],
},
{
            effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
            actions: ['kms:Decrypt'],
            resources: [secretStack.TheSecret.EncryptionKey.KeyArn],
}
```

You can see example code for this workaround with more details [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/14213#issuecomment-823278483).